# Re-login event with Laravel-passport gives error (401) "Unauthenticated"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth, laravel-passport

I have the next problem.
I use `Laravel Passport` with grand type "password" to authenticate user. After make request `POST` to `"oauth/token"` I receive valid access_token and it is "OK".
But if I try repeat login event and send request again with the same client credentials without reloading the page I receive error `(401) "Unauthenticated".`
Logout event with `session->flush()` has no effect.
If I reload the page, then I again can `"login"`, but the second attempt give me the same issue.
How to solve this problem? It very necessary for login/logout logic.

Comment: How can you login when you are already logged in? I do not understand this workflow.

Comment: It is  happens when I 1) `"login"` -> then `"logout"` -> then `"login"` again, or 2) `"login" -> "login"`. On this steps a receive error. During all this steps i does not restart and reload the page because I build SPA application. If i restart the page everything became "Ok"

Comment: When I re-login and send credential to `"oauth/token"` it return new `"access_token"` but `Auth::user()` became invalid and gives error `(401) "Unauthenticated"`